# Notice: Undefined variable: id in PHP

Tags: php, sql

I am getting an `undefined variable` error while executing below code:

```
if ($amount != NULL) {
    $host = 'localhost';
    $user = 'root';
    $pass = '';
    $db = 'deedok';
    $connection = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);
    echo 'connected_deedok';
    if (!$conn){
        die('Database Connection Lost.');
    }
        $query_deedok = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE amount='$amount'";
            $query_deedok_result = mysqli_query($connection, $query_deedok);
    if ($query_deedok_result != NULL) {
        while($query_deedok_result_rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_deedok_result)) {
            $name = $query_deedok_result_rows['name'];
            $id = $query_deedok_result_rows['id'];
            $description = $query_deedok_result_rows['description'];
        }
    }
    echo $name;
    echo $id;
    echo $description;
}
```

I have already assigned value to `$amount` and also there is not database connection error.

Comment: It might be duplicate but please help me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this, and it will work:

```
if ($amount) {
                $host = 'localhost';
                $user = 'root';
                $pass = '';
                $db = 'deedok';
                $connection = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);
                echo 'connected_deedok';
                if (!$conn){
                    die('Database Connection Lost.');
                }
                    $query_deedok = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE amount='" .  $amount . "'";
                        $query_deedok_result = mysqli_query($connection, $query_deedok);
                if ($query_deedok_result != NULL) {
                    while($query_deedok_result_rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_deedok_result)) {
                        $name = $query_deedok_result_rows['name'];
                        $id = $query_deedok_result_rows['id'];
                        $description = $query_deedok_result_rows['description'];
                    }
                        }
        echo $name;
        echo $id;
        echo $description;
            }
```

Your $amount variable is not parsed and will not be replaced with the assigned value as you have included it in quotes.

Comment: not working. Same Error

Comment: @Strange I updated my answer. Try to change condition to if ($amount)

Comment: Sorry, but no luck with that also.

Comment: Thanks for your help. :) It isn't working because there is no data in database matching to $amount variable.